# Unable to remove the effective user from editing rights of protected range using script - google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

In google sheets I'm trying to use a script to make a protected range.

I'd like the script to make a protected range that ONLY the owner can edit, and no one else, however the script has to work when it runs for a user who is NOT the owner.

When I'm logged in as the owner of the spreadsheet and I run the code from script editor, it works fine - it creates a protected range G1:G10 that only the owner can edit.

However when I run the script while logged in as a user who is NOT the owner, the permissions of the protected range allows BOTH the user AND the owner ability to edit the range. I'm aware of [this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) and [this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#protect()), on the google developers documentation, however I can't see anything that'll help me.

Here's my code:

```
function setProtections() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var owner = ss.getOwner();
  var effectiveUser = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  var range = ss.getRange('G1:G10');
  var protection = range.protect()
  var editors = protection.getEditors();
  protection.removeEditors(editors);
  protection.addEditor(owner);
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[removeEditors()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#removeEditors(String)) does not allow the current user to be removed:

> Removes the given array of users from the list of editors for the protected sheet or range. Note that if any of the users are members of a Google Group that has edit permission, or if all users in the domain have edit permission, those users will still be able to edit the protected area. **Neither the owner of the spreadsheet nor the current user can be removed.**

However, you can use an [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) created by the **owner** that will run your `setProtections()` method as the user that created the Trigger [**owner**] - even if it is triggered by another user.

Example: [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) onEdit()

```
function installedOnEditTrigger (e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];

  //Checks if the sheet edit happened in the 7th column "G"
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 7) {
    var range = ss.getRange('G1:G10');
    var protection = range.protect()
    var editors = protection.getEditors();
    //Removes all editors - owners can not be removed
    protection.removeEditors(editors);
  }
}
```

Comment: As user "A", I have not been able to initiate an installable trigger owned by user "B".