# Google Script protect entire row when edited cell is changed to a certain value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been trying to make a script to protect a row when one of the drop down values from the row is set to a certain value ('ON HOLD'). The closest I've been to finding a solution was ([Protect row when drop down menu changes to “Locked” using app scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52273116/protect-row-when-drop-down-menu-changes-to-locked-using-app-scripts)) unfortunately that solution isn't descriptive so I don't know where to begin changing it. This is what I have so far on my solution

```
function onEdit(event){
var eventsheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var editedcell = eventsheet.getActiveCell();

var step = event.range;
var step2 = step.getRow();

Logger.log(step2);

var protectcol = 5;

if(editedcell.getColumn() == protectcol){
  if(editedcell.getDisplayValue() == 'ON HOLD'){
    var protectionrg = step2.protect();
    protectionrg.addEditor('Email@mail.com'); //Entire Row Protect
  }
 } 
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: There's not a good way to do what you're attempting. Essentially you're trying to have a protected sheet, that is totally available to edit (effectively unprotected) then setting up exceptiong ranges as on and off. It could be done, but I'd recommend finding a different approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Here is a sample code:

```
function onEdit(event){
var eventsheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var editedcell = event.range;

var rowRange = eventsheet.getRange("A"+editedcell.getRow()+":"+editedcell.getRow());

Logger.log(rowRange.getA1Notation());

var protectcol = 5;

  if(editedcell.getColumn() == protectcol){
    if(editedcell.getDisplayValue() == 'ON HOLD'){
      var protectionrg = rowRange.protect();
      protectionrg.addEditor('Email@mail.com'); //Entire Row Protect
      protectionrg.removeEditors(protectionrg.getEditors());
      Logger.log("PROTECTED");
    }
    else{
      //Remove protection
      var protections = eventsheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
      protections.forEach(protection => {
        var protectedRange = protection.getRange();
        if(protectedRange.getRow() == editedcell.getRow()){
          //Remove protection
          protection.remove();
        }
      });
    }
  } 
}
```

### Pre-requisite:

Use Installable On-Edit Trigger

[image]

### Modifications done:

- [getRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrow) returns an integer. If you want to use `protect()`, you need to get either `sheet` or `range` object. In your case, you want to protect the entire row. Hence you need to get the `range` of the entire row. I used [Sheet.getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangea1notation) to get the `range` of the entire row, where `a1Notation` is in this format `A1:1` (to select row1)
- When the cell in columnE is set to `ON HOLD`, protect the entire row by adding your preferred editor and by removing existing editors using [removeEditors(emailAddresses)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#removeeditorsemailaddresses)

> **Note:**
>
> `removeEditors()` does not allow the current user to be removed. If the sheet was modified by another user (not Email@mail.com) and set it to `ON HOLD`. Your simple `onEdit` trigger won't be able to remove this another user as an editor in your protected range. As a workaround, you need to use `onEdit` installable trigger, to run the code created by the owner.
>
> Reference: [Unable to remove the effective user from editing rights of protected range using script - google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45563078/unable-to-remove-the-effective-user-from-editing-rights-of-protected-range-using)

- Lastly, When the cell in columnE is set any value other than `ON HOLD`, get all protected range in the current sheet using [getProtections(type)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getprotectionstype), with protection type set to `RANGE`. Then loop all existing protection. Check if the protected range's row index is the same with the modified cell's row index. Remove protection using [remove()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#remove)

Comment: Please let me know if you encountered some issues so i could update the answer accordingly

Comment: Luckily haven't encountered any issues yet, this solution is working though! Thanks very much for the help